# Hugo Replace but Ignore Case-sensitive

Tags: go, hugo, ssg

With this code but without case sensitive. I want replace all word contain Esports, esports, eSports, ESports etc..

```
{{ $content := replace $content "Esports"  "<a href=\"https://example.com/esports/\" >Esports</a>" 1 }}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [replaceRE](https://gohugo.io/functions/replacere/) which does a regex match and then use the i flag to make it case-insensitive.

```
{{ $content | replaceRE "(?i:esports)" "<a href=\"https://example.com/esports/\" >Esports</a>" }}
```

You may need to [tweak](https://github.com/google/re2/wiki/Syntax) the flags or the regex. This is just the gist. I have not tested it.

Comment: Its work but how to limit only one replace?

Comment: @mobagenie, please ask a new question for this. This answer is regarding your original question. I dont know how to replace a single word, in the worst case you can craft some regex.

Comment: Ok thanks i will post it